# TLF find element position

Tags: actionscript-3, tlf, textflow

I got a issue with the TLF trying to find the position of an element (e.g. LinkElement), before it is added to the display list.

I tried the following code:

1. Create my textFlow:

   ```
   var textFlow:TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(MY_HTML_STRING,
   TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
   ```
2. Grab all the Element I need:

   ```
   var lElem:Array = findLinkElement(textFlow, []);

   private function findLinkElement(group:FlowGroupElement, arr:Array):Array {
       var childGroups:Array = [];
       for (var i:int = 0; i < group.numChildren; i++) {
           var element:FlowElement = group.getChildAt(i);
           if (element is LinkElement) {
               arr.push(element as LinkElement);
           } else if (element is FlowGroupElement) {
               childGroups.push(element);
           }
       }

       for (i = 0; i < childGroups.length; i++) {
           var childGroup:FlowGroupElement = childGroups[i];
           findLinkElement(childGroup, arr);               
       }

       return arr;
   }
   ```
3. For each element found try to get the boundaries:

   ```
   for each (var le:LinkElement in lElem){
       var abs:int = le.getAbsoluteStart(); 
       var tl:TextLine = le.getTextFlow().flowComposer.getLineAt(abs).getTextLine(true);
       var rect:Rectangle = tl.getAtomBounds(tl.getAtomIndexAtCharIndex(abs));   
   }
   ```

It seems I can't retrieve the Textline because the flowComposer is null.

Any idea how I can get the boundaries / why the composer is always null?

Comment: Can you show more code? For example, what is your `findLinkElement()` method doing? The answer to why `flowComposer` is null seems to lie there.

Comment: sure, just added the findLinkElement() code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that the flowComposer is null. It's actually an object, but you've got such a long chain of objects in this expression and something else in that chain is null:

`var tl:TextLine = le.getTextFlow().flowComposer.getLineAt(abs).getTextLine(true);`

The issue is is that you are getting the character index of each `LinkElement` -- this is not the line number. So when you do `flowComposer.getLineAt(abs)` it's returning null because that line does not exist.

Instead, you want to use `flowComposer.getLineAtPosition(abs)`. Also, as an optimization the entire flow may not have been generated. So before you do this, it is wise to call `flowComposer.composeToPosition(abs)`.

Below is your code that I've modified to do the above. You may not need the `composeToPosition()` call, it could actually be a performance issue doing it many times inside of a loop. I'll leave that for you to decide.

Here's the code that I used (minus the declaration of my `html` variable). The pertinent code that I modified is inside that `for each` loop:

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite;
stage.addChild(container);
var textFlow:TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(html, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
var controller:ContainerController = new ContainerController(container, 200,200);
textFlow.flowComposer.addController(controller);
textFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();
var links:Array = findLinkElement(textFlow, []);

// modified this code
for each (var le:LinkElement in links){
    var abs:int = le.getAbsoluteStart(); 
    var composer:IFlowComposer = le.getTextFlow().flowComposer;
    composer.composeToPosition(abs);
    var textFlowLine:TextFlowLine = composer.findLineAtPosition(abs);
    var tl:TextLine = textFlowLine.getTextLine(true);
    var rect:Rectangle = tl.getAtomBounds(tl.getAtomIndexAtCharIndex(abs));   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, I understand the problem. I tried you code but keep getting a 
   RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds.
 at flash.text.engine::TextLine/getAtomBounds()

I tested with a dummy html string :
   var html:String = "<b>dfdfdffdf</b><a    href=\"dfdfdf\">sdfsdfsdf</a>xcwxcxcwxcwxcq</br></br><br><a    href=\"dfdfdf\">sdfsdfsdf</a>";

Comment: The Range Error actually appears when the HTML is 'multi lined'.